# It is a best practice use a Primary Key in a serializer who do not represent a Model Object?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an endpoint in Django for a post REST API. I put the parameters of the post body on a class, to handle it internally, but the senior developer says it is better to use a serializer. I create a serializer and everything worked perfectly until the same senior says I have to add a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.

That is when my confusing started because this serializer is not for a Model, but for the body of the request object (who has 3 parameters, one mandatory and two optional), and when I added the mandatory parameters as PrimaryKeyRelatedField, I start to receive on the validated_data an empty OrderedDict()

My questions are:

1. It makes sense to have a PrimaryKeyRelatedField in a serializer who does not represent a Model?
2. In case it makes sense, how I can make it work (or why when I make one of the fields primary key, I receive an empty dict?)

PS: I make sure to send the right data to the endpoint, so this is not a case of receiving an empty OrderedDict because I did not send the mandatory field

Comment: From the doc, *"`PrimaryKeyRelatedField` may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its primary key."* If there is no *relation*, no use

Comment: I will use @ArakkalAbu as the answer because I use his argument with my senior developer and he accepts it.